# The app crashes when file is not selected by file picker

Tags: android

I am trying to build an OCR app using Google's API. Now this activity lets user select an image file using file picker, from where text is extracted. The app works fine if a user selects an image file but if you open file picker and do not select file then the app crashes.
Suppose you clicked on browse button and file picker opens but you do not select any file and press back button then it that case app crashes,but if you will select a file then it works fine.
Here I am attaching the code.

```
package com.example.rahulranjan.synthesize;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.Text;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ocr extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b, convert;
    EditText t;
    Uri uri;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String str = "";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    String text;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private String imagePath = "";
    TextView txtView;
   StringBuilder strBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ocr);



        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        txtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(" */* ");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

            }
        });

        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Syntesize Text");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        String fileSelected = data.getStringExtra("fileSelected");
        Bundle result = data.getExtras();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                // Get the URI of the selected file

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                t.setText(uri.getPath().toString());


                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
                if (!txtRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                    // Shows if your Google Play services is not up to date or OCR is not supported for the device
                    //   txtView.setText("Detector dependencies are not yet available");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detector dependencies are not yet available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    // Set the bitmap taken to the frame to perform OCR Operations.
                    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                    SparseArray items = txtRecognizer.detect(frame);
                   StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                        // The following Process is used to show how to use lines & elements as well
                        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                            TextBlock item = (TextBlock) items.valueAt(i);
                            strBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                            strBuilder.append(".");
                            for (Text line : item.getComponents()) {
                                //extract scanned text lines here
                                Log.v("lines", line.getValue());
                                for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                                    //extract scanned text words here
                                    Log.v("element", element.getValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    strBuilder2 = strBuilder;
                }

                    txtView.setText(strBuilder2.toString());
                }

            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }




    public void clear(View view)
    {
        txtView.setText("");
    }


    public void convert(View view)
    {
      String data = strBuilder2.toString();


             File gpxfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Syntesize Text"+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".txt");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile)) {
            try {
                writer.append(data);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your logcat!!! what is the exception you got

Comment: Just a wild guess when you back press inside `onActivityResult` data can be `null`. So i think its probably a NPE. So move `fileSelected` and `result` inside the `if (data != null)` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be NPE move these two lines

```
    String fileSelected = data.getStringExtra("fileSelected");
    Bundle result = data.getExtras();
```

inside

```
 if (data != null) {
```

final result

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            // Get the URI of the selected file

     String fileSelected = data.getStringExtra("fileSelected");
      Bundle result = data.getExtras();

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            t.setText(uri.getPath().toString());


            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
            if (!txtRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                // Shows if your Google Play services is not up to date or OCR is not supported for the device
                //   txtView.setText("Detector dependencies are not yet available");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detector dependencies are not yet available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                // Set the bitmap taken to the frame to perform OCR Operations.
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray items = txtRecognizer.detect(frame);
               StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                    // The following Process is used to show how to use lines & elements as well
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        TextBlock item = (TextBlock) items.valueAt(i);
                        strBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                        strBuilder.append(".");
                        for (Text line : item.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text lines here
                            Log.v("lines", line.getValue());
                            for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                                //extract scanned text words here
                                Log.v("element", element.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                strBuilder2 = strBuilder;
            }

                txtView.setText(strBuilder2.toString());
            }

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

also better check for `requestCode` too

condition should be

```
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && requestCode==7) {

    //your code

   }
```